# Cannot associate products programmatically

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am developing a magento module in which configurable and simple products are created programmatically. Following code creates both configurable and simple products but does not associate them:

```
$sProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$sProduct
    ->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
    ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
    ->setSku($sku)
    ->setName($name)
    ->setPrice($price)
    ->setAttributeSetId($set_id) //id of set which contains size_range_c attribute
    ->setData("size_range_c", $option_id)
    ->setData("color", $colorId) //another attribute in set but not required
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setShortDescription($short_description)
    ->setTaxClassId(0);

$sProduct->setStockData(array(
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => $qty
));

$sProduct->save();

$cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$cProduct->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setSku($csku)
    ->setName($cname)
    ->setPrice($price)
    ->setAttributeSetId($set_id) //same set is used for both configurable and simple product
    ->setUrlKey($url)
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setShortDescription($short_description)
    ->setTaxClassId(0);

$all_child_products = array();
$all_child_products[$sProduct->getId()] = array(
    $sv = array('attribute_id' => $attrId, //attrbute id of size_range_c
                'label' => $attr_name, //option name
                'value_index' => $option_id, //option_id
                'pricing_value' => 0, 
                'is_percent' => 0)
);

$size_values = array();
$size_values[] = $sv;

$_attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'size_range_c');
$attribute = $_attributes->getFirstItem(); //get data for size_range_c

$cProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($all_child_products);
$cProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData(array(
    array_merge($attribute->getData(), array('label' => '', 'values' => $size_values))
));

$cProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$cProduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

$cProduct->save();
```

Basically, I create a configurable product for each color and then have a simple product for each size of that color and then associate them. size_range_c attribute is required for both configurable and simple products. When I look at these products from admin panel everything seems fine. I have even tried to manually associate simple products to configurable but products created programmatically do not appear in associated products section.

Answer (score 0):

> I have even tried to manually associate simple products to
>   configurable but products created programmatically do not appear in
>   associated products section.

Any configurable product is created with one or many configurable attributes, let say Color for this case. An configurable product can not have two associated products with same attribute value, let say with same red color. Also Magento not show in "Associated Products" section even if we click on "Reset Filter" all products. If configurable product is made it after Color attribute, it will show all simple product that have set some value of color attribute (color is not null), so i think that for your products you not have set for any products the color attribute so it not show any products in "Associated Products".

A quick method to programmaticly associate a simple product to an configurable product is to use this code:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->saveProducts($pConfigurable, array($idSimpleProduct));
```

Note: $pConfigurable is instance of configurable product and $idSimpleProduct is id of simple product what you want to associate. Also simple product must have set color attribute before use this function. If other simple product is already associated with same value of color the association will be overridden.

Another solution to associate a simple product to a configurable product (and magento way) it might be as i seen it in your code to set data with setConfigurableAttributesData to a configurable product model instance and then call save, but i think that array data is incomplete in your code sample.

Comment: I'm using the code you have in this answer, but it will not show in store. It links the simple products to the configurable one, but there's no link in DB. How can I link color to the configurable product?